# What are the number of failing K-12 schools in America?

Tags: united-states, education

Does the government, or third party, provide a definition for what constitutes a failing public school in the United States, K-12?

Are there government supplied, and potentially third party sources, for the number of failing public schools in America?  Associated metrics would be helpful like the number of children impacted, percentages of total students, and trend analysis.

Comment: After looking at the definitions, or lack thereof in the literature, I am going to delete the question.  Thanks Blip for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article quotes the Department of Education](https://www.fairtest.org/esea-ten-percent-u-s-schools-labeled-failing) (emphasis mine):

> **Nearly ten percent** of the nation’s schools – **8652** of some 91,000 – already face the first level of sanctions under the federal Elementary and Secondary Education Act (ESEA). According to a July 1 press release from the U.S. Department of Education (DoE), the schools failed to make sufficient progress on state assessments. The 3.5 million students in those schools – all of which received ESEA Title I funds – are eligible to transfer to other schools.

Whether or not that particular definition of 'failing' (ie, calculating progress via state assessment testing) is universally agreed upon is, of course, up to debate and interpretation.

EDIT:

I attempted to find more recent statistics but, alas, it appears that 15 years later, the louder narrative is how standardized testing is a poor measurement, so I'm not sure there's going to be stats to directly compare against the aforementioned ones.

EDIT 2:

> Does the government, or third party, provide a definition for what constitutes a failing public school in the United States, K-12?

Yes. But it varies from department to department, legislation to legislation, private entity to private entity. So while there are definitions of "failing school" there isn't a single, universally shared definition.

Comment: Please note that this is from 2001.  Anything more current?

Comment: @KDog ah, good catch. That might be dated. Let me see if I can find updated numbers.

Comment: Keep the post though as it could form part of a trend analysis

Comment: @KDog I tried. But can't find any direct comparison numbers today. The question might need to define 'failing' in a very specific way to find numbers that can be compared from one decade to the next.

Comment: Are those sanctions related to some idea of "failing" ? The question asks for some idea of failure, which is missing here.

Comment: @indigochild it's defined in the quote: "first level of sanctions under the federal Elementary and Secondary Education Act" but yes, I think that's part of the challenge of this question...there is no universal definition of what "failing school" means.

Comment: Me too.  Couldn't find anything. If nothing more comes up, I'll award you the answer.

Comment: Take a look at this  https://www.ed.gov/news/press-releases/duncan-says-82-percent-americas-schools-could-fail-under-nclb-year

Comment: @KDog that reinforces the issue of there not being a universal definition. That is talking about NCLB and is making the point that that, too, isn't a good definition of failing.

Comment: @blip - If that's true, then the answer should be "there is no official policy on what a failing school is."  This answer is somewhat misleading, because it would suggests that Title I is controlling what "failure" for a school means.

Comment: @indigochild I guess I see two different questions...the one in the title, and the one in the body. Let me address the part in the body

Comment: @blip - Your edit says that the federal government does have definitions of a failing school. Can you provide some of those definitions? Your current quote doesn't do that.

Comment: @indigochild  the law changed from the ESEA to NCLB and the measurement did too

Comment: AYP I think is currently in force as the definition of failing

Comment: @KDog - The measurement isn't an issue to me. The "Edit 2" area says that there are definitions of failing, but that evidence isn't within the answer. I'm looking for an example definition.

Comment: @indigochild  Here's the definition: No Child Left Behind requires all U.S. public schools to meet annual targets — called Adequate Yearly Progress (AYP) — aimed at making all students 100 percent proficient in reading or language arts and math by 2014

Comment: @KDog - That is not a definition of failure or success. That is just one of thousands of statutory requirements that fall upon schools. Failure to comply with a statute does not indicate the school is a failure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59313/discussion-between-indigochild-and-k-dog).